# AWS CloudFormation Wordpress template. WaitCondition timed out

Tags: templates, amazon-web-services, cloud, aws-cloudformation

I am reading about Amazon CloudFormation and want to launch this CF template https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-templates-us-east-1/WordPress_Single_Instance_With_RDS.template which has been provided by "Getting Started" of Amazon.

Before I have removed default VPC and subnets, so now I need to specify its directly. After googling I have edited above template to such view:

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion" : "2010-09-09",

  "Description" : "AWS CloudFormation Sample Template WordPress_Single_Instance_With_RDS: WordPress is web software you can use to create a website or blog. This template installs a single-instance WordPress deployment that uses an Amazon RDS database instance for storage. It demonstrates using the AWS CloudFormation bootstrap scripts to install packages and files when an instance is launched. **WARNING** This template creates an Amazon EC2 instance and an Amazon RDS database instance. You will be billed for the AWS resources used if you create a stack from this template.",

  "Parameters" : {

    "KeyName": {
      "Description" : "Name of an existing EC2 KeyPair to enable SSH access to the instances",
      "Type": "String",
      "MinLength": "1",
      "MaxLength": "255",
      "AllowedPattern" : "[\\x20-\\x7E]*",
      "ConstraintDescription" : "can contain only ASCII characters."
    },

    "InstanceType" : {
      "Description" : "WebServer EC2 instance type",
      "Type" : "String",
      "Default" : "t1.micro",
      "AllowedValues" : [ "t1.micro", "t2.micro", "t2.small", "t2.medium", "m3.medium", "m3.large", "m3.xlarge", "m3.2xlarge" ],
      "ConstraintDescription" : "must be a valid EC2 instance type."
    },

    "myVPC": {
        "Description" : "Id of my VPC",
        "Type"        : "String",
        "Default"     : "vpc-1bcf9e7e"
    },

    "MySubnet": {
        "Description" : "My subnet from my VPC",
        "Type": "String",
        "Default": "subnet-75eec810"
    },

    "RDSSubnets": {
        "Description" : "RDS subnets from my VPC",
        "Type": "CommaDelimitedList",
        "Default": "subnet-75eec810,subnet-448bcc33"
    },

    "DBClass" : {
      "Default" : "db.t1.micro",
      "Description" : "Database instance class",
      "Type" : "String",
      "AllowedValues" : [ "db.t1.micro", "db.t2.micro", "db.t2.small", "db.t2.medium", "db.m3.medium", "db.m3.large", "db.m3.xlarge", "db.m3.2xlarge" ],
      "ConstraintDescription" : "must select a valid database instance type."
    },

    "DBName" : {
      "Default": "wordpress",
      "Description" : "The WordPress database name",
      "Type": "String",
      "MinLength": "1",
      "MaxLength": "64",
      "AllowedPattern" : "[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*",
      "ConstraintDescription" : "must begin with a letter and contain only alphanumeric characters."
    },

    "DBUsername" : {
      "Default": "admin",
      "NoEcho": "true",
      "Description" : "The WordPress database admin account username",
      "Type": "String",
      "MinLength": "1",
      "MaxLength": "16",
      "AllowedPattern" : "[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*",
      "ConstraintDescription" : "must begin with a letter and contain only alphanumeric characters."
    },

    "DBPassword" : {
      "Default": "password",
      "NoEcho": "true",
      "Description" : "The WordPress database admin account password",
      "Type": "String",
      "MinLength": "8",
      "MaxLength": "41",
      "AllowedPattern" : "[a-zA-Z0-9]*",
      "ConstraintDescription" : "must contain only alphanumeric characters."
    },

    "DBAllocatedStorage" : {
      "Default": "5",
      "Description" : "The size of the database (Gb)",
      "Type": "Number",
      "MinValue": "5",
      "MaxValue": "1024",
      "ConstraintDescription" : "must be between 5 and 1024Gb."
    },
    "SSHLocation" : {
      "Description" : " The IP address range that can be used to SSH to the EC2 instances",
      "Type": "String",
      "MinLength": "9",
      "MaxLength": "18",
      "Default": "0.0.0.0/0",
      "AllowedPattern": "(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})/(\\d{1,2})",
      "ConstraintDescription": "must be a valid IP CIDR range of the form x.x.x.x/x."
    }
  },

  "Mappings" : {
      "AWSInstanceType2Arch" : {
      "t1.micro"    : { "Arch" : "PV64"  },
      "t2.micro"    : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "t2.small"    : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "t2.medium"   : { "Arch" : "HVM64"  },
      "m3.medium"   : { "Arch" : "PV64"   },
      "m3.large"    : { "Arch" : "PV64"   },
      "m3.xlarge"   : { "Arch" : "PV64"   },
      "m3.2xlarge"  : { "Arch" : "PV64"   }
    },

    "AWSRegionArch2AMI" : {
      "us-east-1"      : { "PV64" : "ami-7c807d14", "HVM64" : "ami-76817c1e" },
      "us-west-2"      : { "PV64" : "ami-1b3b462b", "HVM64" : "ami-d13845e1" },
      "us-west-1"      : { "PV64" : "ami-a8d3d4ed", "HVM64" : "ami-f0d3d4b5" },
      "eu-west-1"      : { "PV64" : "ami-672ce210", "HVM64" : "ami-892fe1fe" },
      "ap-southeast-1" : { "PV64" : "ami-56b7eb04", "HVM64" : "ami-a6b6eaf4" },
      "ap-northeast-1" : { "PV64" : "ami-25dd9324", "HVM64" : "ami-29dc9228" },
      "ap-southeast-2" : { "PV64" : "ami-6bf99c51", "HVM64" : "ami-d9fe9be3" },
      "sa-east-1"      : { "PV64" : "ami-c7e649da", "HVM64" : "ami-c9e649d4" },
      "us-gov-west-1"  : { "PV64" : "ami-ab4a2d88", "HVM64" : "ami-a54a2d86" },
      "cn-north-1"     : { "PV64" : "ami-cab82af3", "HVM64" : "ami-ccb82af5" }
    }
  },

  "Resources" : {

    "WebServer": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
      "Metadata" : {
        "AWS::CloudFormation::Init" : {
          "config" : {
            "packages" : {
              "yum" : {
                "httpd"     : [],
                "php"       : [],
                "php-mysql" : []
              }
            },
            "sources" : {
              "/var/www/html" : "http://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz"
            },
            "files" : {
              "/var/www/html/wordpress/wp-config.php" : {
                "content" : { "Fn::Join" : ["", [
                  "<?php\n",
                  "define('DB_NAME',          '", {"Ref" : "DBName"}, "');\n",
                  "define('DB_USER',          '", {"Ref" : "DBUsername"}, "');\n",
                  "define('DB_PASSWORD',      '", {"Ref" : "DBPassword" }, "');\n",
                  "define('DB_HOST',          '", {"Fn::GetAtt" : ["DBInstance", "Endpoint.Address"]},"');\n",
                  "define('DB_CHARSET',       'utf8');\n",
                  "define('DB_COLLATE',       '');\n"
                ]] },
                "mode" : "000644",
                "owner" : "root",
                "group" : "root"
              }
            },
            "services" : {
              "sysvinit" : {
                "httpd"    : { "enabled" : "true", "ensureRunning" : "true" },
                "sendmail" : { "enabled" : "false", "ensureRunning" : "false" }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "Properties": {
        "SubnetId": { "Ref": "MySubnet" },
        "ImageId" : { "Fn::FindInMap" : [ "AWSRegionArch2AMI", { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" },
                          { "Fn::FindInMap" : [ "AWSInstanceType2Arch", { "Ref" : "InstanceType" }, "Arch" ] } ] },
        "InstanceType"   : { "Ref" : "InstanceType" },
        "SecurityGroupIds" : [ {"Ref" : "WebServerSecurityGroup"} ],
        "KeyName"        : { "Ref" : "KeyName" },
        "UserData"       : { "Fn::Base64" : { "Fn::Join" : ["", [
          "#!/bin/bash\n",
          "yum update -y aws-cfn-bootstrap\n",

          "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -s ", { "Ref" : "AWS::StackId" }, " -r WebServer ",
          "         --region ", { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" }, "\n",

          "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e $? '", { "Ref" : "WaitHandle" }, "'\n",

          "# Setup correct file ownership\n",
          "chown -R apache:apache /var/www/html/wordpress\n",

          "# Add keys and salts to the config file\n",
          "wp_config=/var/www/html/wordpress/wp-config.php\n",
          "GET https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/ >> $wp_config\n",
          "echo \"define('WPLANG'            , '');\" >> $wp_config\n",
          "echo \"define('WP_DEBUG'          , false);\" >> $wp_config\n", 
          "echo \"\\$table_prefix  = 'wp_';\" >> $wp_config\n",
          "echo \"if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )\" >> $wp_config\n",
          "echo \"    define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');\" >> $wp_config\n",
          "echo \"require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');\" >> $wp_config\n"

        ]]}}
      }
    },

    "WaitHandle" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::CloudFormation::WaitConditionHandle"
    },

    "WaitCondition" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::CloudFormation::WaitCondition",
      "DependsOn" : "WebServer",
      "Properties" : {
        "Handle" : {"Ref" : "WaitHandle"},
        "Timeout" : "1200"
      }
    },

    "DBInstance" : {
      "Type": "AWS::RDS::DBInstance",
      "Properties": {
        "DBSubnetGroupName" : { "Ref" : "MyDBSubnetGroup" },
        "VPCSecurityGroups" : [ { "Ref" : "DBSecurityGroup" } ],
        "DBName"            : { "Ref" : "DBName" },
        "Engine"            : "MySQL",
        "MasterUsername"    : { "Ref" : "DBUsername" },
        "DBInstanceClass"   : { "Ref" : "DBClass" },
        "DBSecurityGroups"  : [{ "Ref" : "DBSecurityGroup" }],
        "AllocatedStorage"  : { "Ref" : "DBAllocatedStorage" },
        "MasterUserPassword": { "Ref" : "DBPassword" }
      }
    },

    "DBSecurityGroup": {
      "Type": "AWS::RDS::DBSecurityGroup",
      "Properties": {
        "EC2VpcId" : { "Ref" : "myVPC" },
        "DBSecurityGroupIngress": { "EC2SecurityGroupId": { "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "WebServerSecurityGroup", "GroupId" ] } },
        "GroupDescription"      : "Frontend Access"
      }
    },

    "WebServerSecurityGroup" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
      "Properties" : {
        "VpcId" : {"Ref" : "myVPC"},
        "GroupDescription" : "Enable HTTP access via port 80 and SSH access",
        "SecurityGroupIngress" : [
          {"IpProtocol" : "tcp", "FromPort" : "80", "ToPort" : "80", "CidrIp" : "0.0.0.0/0"},
          {"IpProtocol" : "tcp", "FromPort" : "22", "ToPort" : "22", "CidrIp" : { "Ref" : "SSHLocation"}}
        ]
      }
    },

    "MyDBSubnetGroup" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::RDS::DBSubnetGroup",
      "Properties" : {
        "DBSubnetGroupDescription" : "Subnets available for the RDS DB Instance",
        "SubnetIds" : { "Ref" : "RDSSubnets" }
      }
    }
  },

  "Outputs" : {
    "WebsiteURL" : {
      "Value" : { "Fn::Join" : ["", ["http://", { "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "WebServer", "PublicDnsName" ]}, "/wordpress"]] },
      "Description" : "WordPress Website"
    }
  }
}
```

http://pastebin.com/0cS9Ba0t

Unfortunately now I have error which I dont know how to fix:

```
CREATE_FAILED   AWS::CloudFormation::WaitCondition  WaitCondition   WaitCondition timed out. Received 0 conditions when expecting 1
```

[image]

What should be changed in this template?

Answer (score 2):

The template includes a wait condition. After the EC2 instance was started completely it calls cfn-signal. It seems like the installation and configuration of Wordpress fails on your machine.

Double check the VPC and the subnet while creating the CloudFormation stack.

- The subnet must be part of the VPC.
- The subnet has to be a public subnet (Route to IGW).
- Make sure all EC2 instances will get a public IP address by default when launched into the subnet (configuration of subnet).

Answer (score 0):

in my case the problem was the username and password of the DB instance, and the stack name had already been used by other configurations. So I choose a unique name for the stack and used only char for dbname and password.